# evaluating min and max probability for at least on event occurred

Tags: probability

I am going over probability, and came across the following question:

> Suppose your right knee is sore 15% of the time, and your left knee is
> sore 10% of the time. What is the largest possible percentage of time
> that at least one of your knees is sore? What is the smallest possible
> percentage of time that at least one of your knees is sore?

We have $P(\text{right}) = 0.15$ and $P(\text{left}) = 0.1$

From subadditivity $P(\text{right} \cup \text{left})\leq P(\text{right}) + P(\text{left}) = 0.15. + 0.1 = 0.25$

In the case that $\text{left} \subset \text{right}$ we get $P(\text{left}) < P(\text{right}) = 0.15$

1. Because we are told "at least one of your knees" then we have to account that one or more knees are sore?
2. Can we conclude that left and right event are disjoint?

Comment: 1) Yes, find the highest and lowest possible probabilities that one or more of your knees are sore.  2) Can we *conclude* that?  No, but if we were to hypothetically *assume* that, then that will lead you to part of the answer you seek (*which you already found when you described subadditivity*).

Comment: The punchline is that you have already found your answer... $0.15\leq \Pr(r\cup \ell)\leq 0.25$ and these bounds are tight, as evidenced by the hypothetical scenarios where there was as much or as little overlap between these events as possible.